# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, boolean, operator-keyword

I've reverse engineered this application that I've lost source code to and am unable to get past this error being thrown upon building the application.

The error: `"Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool' "`

On the line

```
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ((-(((this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) > false) ? 1 : 0)) ? 1 : 0);
```

Where

```
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) > false
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `true` compares greater than `false`, so `> false` is equivalent to `!= false`, which you can just remove ==> remove the whole `> false` part.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: I'm not sure what languages allow an ordered comparison between two boolean values, but not C#.

Comment: @EricJ. it's disallowed in the language syntax, but `Comparer<bool>.Default` will perform the comparison I described. This is a C# limitation, it's allowed in IL.

Comment: The question is tagged C#, not IL :-)

Comment: @EricJ. yes, what I mean is that you can *still* write something like `(new[] { true, false, true }).OrderBy(i => i)` and it **will** sort. `bool` comparison is well-defined, but the language doesn't allow you to use comparison operators on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message says it all

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'

There is no concept of order for a boolean in C#.  Two boolean values are either equal, or they are unequal.

If you are trying to get the case where

```
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1
```

is not true, instead use

```
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex != 1
```

For example

```
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = (this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex != 1) ? 0 : 1;
```

or equivalently and probably easier to read

```
this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = (this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

This code will leave the selected index at 1 if it is already 1, and will set it to 0 for any other value.

Comment: One addition you could make to this answer is to suggest that evaluating a bool to obtain 1 or 0 is not a nice thing to do; just use the boolean value directly.

Comment: @DavidArno: He doesn't actually want a bool, he wants a new SelectedIndex value, which is an int.

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: @phoog: Yes, but I prefer to leave them in when explaining a concept (as in this case) or when the order of operations would not be completely clear to a junior level developer (ease code maintenance down the road).

Comment: @EricJ. That seems prudent.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
((this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1) != false)
```

Comment: Double negatives are not very maintenance-friendly.

Comment: Won't downvote for the `!= false`, but it's a definite code-smell.

Comment: Okay. I have not come across any issues with this. I need to learn about why its not a good practice then..

Comment: Anyhow, there is no need of adding `false` into the expression at all, the condition `(this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)` itself returns true if `true` orelse `false`.